# Running a script to SSH into a host, gather user input and send information back to the original host. Unable to get user input

Tags: input, ssh, user-input

I'm currently working on a script that is supposed to do the following:

-- SSH into a remote host

-- Switch to SU

-- Get a list of all the dump records

-- Select a dump record to compile into a log

This is what I initially used:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Get IP address to SSH into
echo Enter Device IP
read vardeviceip

# Remote into Device
ssh -t support@$vardeviceip << EOF

## AFTER LOGIN

# Switch to root
sudo su

# Check number of system boots recorded by journalctl
journalctl --list-boots

# Ask user for which set to get
echo Enter index number you wish to retrieve
read varindexnum

# Compile logs
nohup collect-diag -t collect_all_logs -s oldest_boot=$varindexnum

# List compiled logs and ask user for which log to download
ls -l /var/log/device/dump/
echo Enter timestamp of log to be downloaded
read varlogtimestamp

# Log out of Device
bash -l

EOF
```

When running the script, I'm able to SSH in, but the "read" command is not performed. Why is that?  What can I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know what you mean--the command is listed in the code:
`ssh -t support@$vardeviceip << EOF`

And all the commands afterwards are the ones to be performed after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it.  I had to make a second shell script and run it within the first script, like so:

```
ssh -t support@$vardeviceip "$(cat getlogs.sh)"
```

Thanks anyways!